# Отличие интернационализации от локализации?

Tags: терминология

Не могу понять отличии интернационализации от локализации? Читаю термины и не доходит, дайте пожалуйста простые примеры и разъяснения, заранее спасибо.

> Интернационализа́ция (англ. internationalization) — технологические
> приёмы разработки, упрощающие адаптацию продукта (такого как
> программное или аппаратное обеспечение) к языковым и культурным
> особенностям региона (регионов), отличного от того, в котором
> разрабатывался продукт.
>
> Локализа́ция програ́ммного обеспече́ния — процесс адаптации
> программного обеспечения к культуре какой-либо страны. Как частность —
> перевод пользовательского интерфейса, документации и сопутствующих
> файлов программного обеспечения с одного языка на другой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Интернационализация* (*i18n*) - по сути это создание технологии, а *локализация* - это собственно сам процесс использования технологии.

**Пример**

В Android i18n осуществляется ресурсами распределенными по разным папкам в наименованиями папок: `values-[locale]` или `values-[locale]-r[region]`, например:

```
values-ru     //русский
values-ru-rRU //русский в России
values-ru-rUA //русский с украинским акцентом
values-ru-rKZ //русский с казахской вариацией
```

Понятно, что это работает не просто так, за всем этим стоит некое API, разработанное Google, собственно создание этого API и называется интернационализацией.

Теперь, локализация - это написание ресурсов/кода подчиняющихся правилам интернационализации. В случае Android создание файла (и не только его разумеется) `res/values-ru/strings.xml` и будет локализацией приложения на русский язык.

Answer (score 1):

Дочитали бы до конца [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> Интернационализация — это адаптация продукта для потенциального
> использования практически в любом месте, в то время как локализация —
> это добавление специальных функций для использования в некотором
> определённом регионе. Интернационализация производится на начальных
> этапах разработки, в то время как локализация — для каждого целевого
> языка.

На самом деле если посмотреть применительно к производству то будет видеться разница.

Интернационализация производства и локализация производства

Answer (score 1):

Разницу можно посмотреть на простом примере:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Основное действие приложения
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Что бы иметь возможность выводить приветсвие на разных языках, будем передавать приложению требуемый язык в качестве первого параметра, то есть `args[0]`.
Первым делом необходимо выполнить ***интернационализацию*** приложения, то есть подготовить его код для возможности изменения языка приветствия:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Добавлен механизм, позволяющий позже добавить новые ресурсы
        String lang = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "EN";
        HashMap<String, String> greetings = new HashMap<>();
        greetings.put("EN", "Hello, World!");
        // Основное действие приложения
        System.out.println(greetings.get(lang));
    }
}
```

Теперь наше приложение ***интернационализовано*** и готово к ***локализации***, то есть к добавлению новых ресурсов. Выполним локализацию на русский и украинский языки:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Добавлен механизм, позволяющий позже добавить новые ресурсы
        String lang = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "EN";
        HashMap<String, String> greetings = new HashMap<>();
        greetings.put("EN", "Hello, World!");
        // Добавляем новые ресурсы локализации
        greetings.put("RU", "Привет, Мир!");
        greetings.put("UA", "Привіт, світ!");
        // Основное действие приложения
        System.out.println(greetings.get(lang));
    }
}
```

Осталось вынести ресурсы из кода приложения и добавить проверку передаваемого параметра.